# Let's chat authentication via ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, authentication, chat

I've deployed a Let's Chat application for my own server.

However, instead of using currently built, original Let's Chat web application I would like to develop my own, using its API.

And according to [Let's Chat wiki](https://github.com/sdelements/lets-chat/wiki/API%3A-Authentication):

> Revoke an API Token
>
> In the top-left dropdown menu:
>
> - Select "Auth tokens"
> - Click "Revoke token"
> - Choose "Yes". This will delete any previously generated token.
>
> Basic Authentication
>
> Use the API token as the username when authenticating. The password
>   can be set to anything, but it must not be blank (simply because most
>   clients require it).

So far I've generated own token and tried to send `GET` request to retrieve all rooms that I have in the app, but I've got an error: `401 - Unauthorized` - I've tried to send this request with `{ data: my_token, password: my_random_password }` credentials but without success. So my main question is: **how exactly I can authenticate with Let's Chat API using ajax request?**

I couldn't find any API url / endpoint dedicated for such task - please help.

EDIT:

I've tried also setting headers but it still doesn't work:

```
$.ajax({
    url: CHAT_URL + 'rooms',
    beforeSend: function(xhr){
        xhr.setRequestHeader('username', 'NTczYzZ1111111111111111111JiMWE3MGUwYThiNzZhYjhmYjFjOWJkOTQ5ZDQ2YjhjNWUyMzkwNmMzYjhjMQ==');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('password', '123qwe');
    }
}).done(function(resp){
    console.log('1');
    console.log(resp);
}).done(function(resp){
    console.log('2');
    console.log(resp);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From that wiki page:

> Use the API token as the Bearer token.

This is done by setting the header `Authentication` to the value `bearer YOUR_TOKEN_HERE`

So,

```
 xhr.setRequestHeader('Authentication', 'bearer NTczYzZ1111111111111111111JiMWE3MGUwYThiNzZhYjhmYjFjOWJkOTQ5ZDQ2YjhjNWUyMzkwNmMzYjhjMQ==');
```

If you *want* to use basic authentication, this answers that question

[How to use Basic Auth with jQuery and AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/how-to-use-basic-auth-with-jquery-and-ajax)

Comment: I've tried You suggestion and I'm having an `401 - unauthorized` error :/ Tried with different combination (upper/downcase replacing order etc. but without success)

Comment: (I'm sorry for my previous answer that was the copy of Yours) - at first I've made a mistake and I was using `Authorization` as a header name and when I finally found answer at other website I've pasted it here and didn't realise that You already give me the proper header name (`Authentication` <-- `Authorization`) - really sorry again about that!